# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException in c# Insert of dates

Tags: c#, php, mysql

```
    public void AddFlightToDB(Flight flight, DataTable dt)
    {
        long flightId;
        connectDB();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + FlightTableDB + "(" + FlightFromColumnflights_table+ "," + FlightDistanceColumnflights_table + "," + FlightWindColumnflights_table + "," + FlightTemperatureColumnflights_table + "," + FlightDateColumnflights_table + ") VALUES ('" + flight.From + "','" + flight.Distance + "','" + flight.Wind + "','" + flight.Temperature + "','" + flight.FlightDate + "')";


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

> Table setting:

```
    flights_table   CREATE TABLE `flights_table` (
  `flightId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distance` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wind` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temperature` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`flightId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

> > I have this error: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'from,distance,wind,temperature,date) VALUES
>   ('Opole','35','back','3','2016-12-04' at line 1
>
> The Value of cmd.Commandtext is:
>   "INSERT INTO flights_table(from,distance,wind,temperature,date) VALUES ('Opole','35','back','3','2016-12-04 00:00:00')"

Comment: Do not concatenate your values to form an SQL command text. This will create a lot of problems for your database engine in parsing the inputs. Use instead a parameterized query where each parameter carries the exact datatype to insert in your columns

Comment: By the way, having a field named 'from' is really a bad bad idea.....

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner why is 'from' s bad idea?

Comment: FROM is a reserved keyword. If you have a field with that name you should enclose it in backticks. `(ALT+096)from(ALT+096)`  otherwise the db engine parser will throw a syntax error.

Comment: The same is true for the name `date`. It is another reserved keyword.

Comment: That was my error. Thank you

Comment: I seggest to change these names otherwise you will have the same problem in future

Comment: I changed it. I will remember